# What is the meaning of this strange syntax [SOME_MUTATION] (state) for function definition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

In Vue I see code like:

```
// mutation-types.js
export const SOME_MUTATION = 'SOME_MUTATION'
```

and

```
// store.js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { SOME_MUTATION } from './mutation-types'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { ... },
  mutations: {
    // we can use the ES2015 computed property name feature
    // to use a constant as the function name
    [SOME_MUTATION] (state) {
      // mutate state
    }
  }
})
```

Where the syntax [SOME_MUTATION] (state) comes from? Is [SOME_MUTATION, ANOTHER] (state) also valid syntax? Why SOME_MUTATION (state) (which is valid function syntax) is not used?

How in large Vue project, putting all export const SOME_MUTATION = 'SOME_MUTATION' defintions in separate file really help instead of putting in same file (store.js) ?

Comment: real programmers don't write comments, so why should they read them :p

Comment: But the code comments do not answer my two sub questions: Why SOME_MUTATION (state) (which is valid function syntax) is not used? How in large Vue project, putting all export const SOME_MUTATION = 'SOME_MUTATION' defintions in separate file really help instead of putting in same file (store.js) ?

Comment: @JaromandaX It's funny I found your comment more helpful and friendly than the one from @appleapple. @ace The computed property name is used because you can reuse the constant to name the `action` and `mutation` functions (which usually share the same name), also you can use the constants in components when you are using namespaced modules along with vuex `namespacedHelpers` or something like `this.$store.dispatch(FOO_CONSTANT, bar)`. Basically it reduces typing errors.

Comment: @ace This is a matter of preference, it is actually stated in the docs [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#using-constants-for-mutation-types). "Whether to use constants is largely a preference - it can be helpful in large projects with many developers, but it's totally optional if you don't like them."

Comment: then you should not ask 2 question at first place. (why my last comment is deleted (with 4 upvotes)?

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't quite get what you want to say. Is it a common joke?

Comment: @ace besides, I think design choice is not good to ask on SO.

Answer (score 2):

In this line

`import { SOME_MUTATION } from './mutation-types'`

where you are importing the types into `SOME_MUTATION`, it has a string value. Now to define a function with this name inside an object you need to do

```
{
   [SOME_MUTATION](state) {

   }
}
```

Would be same as (if `SOME_MUTATION` has a value say `changeState`)

```
{
    changeState: function(state){

    }
}
```

And state is by default passed as an argument in mutations.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

We prefer this type of architecture in a Vue application so as to avoid name conflicts in defining Mutations and Actions and Getters across multiple components.

Answer (score 0):

It's a javascript syntax for defining an `object key` programatically/dynamically.

for example, you have a variable:

```
var myFunctionName = "getUsers";
```

you can actually create a `function` inside an `object` using the value of a variable as the function name.

So for example,

```
{
    [myFunctionName]() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

will actually become:

ES6:

```
{
    getUsers() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

or ES5:

```
{
    getUsers: function() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This is not limited to creating functions within an object, but it can be applied to any property within your object.

For example:

```
let myPropertyName = 'user';
{
    [myPropertyName]: {
        name: 'Hello',
        age: 10
    }
}
```

will become:

```
{
    user: {
        name: 'Hello',
        age: 10
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to replace `myFunctionName`